# UIView Transform property to skew a circle to give it a 3D look

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform, catransform3drotate

I am using an `MKMapView` with an added `MKCircleView`. It inherits from `UIView`, so I am able to use the transform property.

It looks pretty flat without a transform, and looks strange next to the pin since it is 3D:

[image]

I would like to skew it to look similar to:

[image]

I have tried playing with examples of setting the `CATransform3DRotate` but the math involved isn't my skill so nothing came even close.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this work? [view.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_4, 1, 0, 0)];

Comment: Does seem to have changed much.

Comment: "and looks strange next to the pin since it is 3D" - yes, but after deforming it, it will look strange on the map since it is 2D.

Comment: That may be true, but I still want to figure out how to do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would fake it with 2d scaling using

```
CGContextScaleCTM
```

You can do it with every UIView:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)];
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 0.6f);
[v setTransform:scale];
```

Scale by factors (1.0, 0.6) and you're done!

If this does not help, you should do a little more, creating your own custom map overlay, as as described in [this tutorial](http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/05/ios-maps-with-image-overlays/)

Good luck!

Comment: Can I do that without subclassing?

Comment: Try with the tutorial in answer, it might be helpful.

Comment: Add a MKOverlayPathView instead of a MKCircleView, and set its path property by using CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect.